# Is it possible to bybass or get through a proxy which requires authentication without knowing the user/pass?

Tags: proxy, tunnel

I need to use Putty to connect to an ssh server on port 22, but the pc where Putty needs to get through has a proxy which requires authentication.  When I insert the proxy address and port in Putty I get a 407 error (Aunthentication Required), but I do not konw the user/pass.

Is there any way I can bybass the proxy authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ask the network administrators for the authentication details.

Comment: OK that is one method.  Are there any others?

Comment: @tastefullvenom Well, if it needs to go through that Proxy, and you need to authenticate on it, not really? Would it be a problem to ask for credentials?

Comment: I have user and id to log on this pc, and I can browse the internet on it and go to any sites.  The browser accesses the internet through this same proxy.  It does not ask me for authentication to browse the internet. Therefore I assume that it is iether using the credentials I used to log in the pc (my user/pass) or else the credentials are saved somewhere and automatically retrieved when I browse.  So how come when I use Putty, and I use my user/pass it still says authentication required?  Do I need to point Putty to a file that is holding my credentials?  If yes where do I find this stored?

Comment: That could be simply because SSH is not allowed by this proxy, at least for you.